# Numba : inputs could not be coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Tags: python, numba

I've been really struggling with numba lately.
Copied this code snippet directly from numba docs and it works fine:

```
@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64, int64[:])], '(n),()->(n)')
def g(x, y, res):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i] = x[i] + y

a = np.arange(5)
g(a,2)
```

Giving y an array results in a grid. Summing 2 arrays is something I do a lot though, so here's the code I came up with by modifying the snippet.

```
@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64[:], int64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n)')
def add_arr(x, y, res):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i] = x[i] + y[i]

p = np.ones(1000000)
q = np.ones(1000000)
r = np.zeros(1000000)

add_arr(p,q)
```

This gives me the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-074c0fd345aa> in <module>()
----> 1 add_arr(p,q)

TypeError: ufunc 'add_arr' not supported for the input types, and the      inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I have encountered this error a few times before but I've no idea what it means or how to fix it. How do I get the desired result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not strictly familiar with numba, but it seems that you are passing 3 arguments instead of 2 like in the pasted, working example. What happens when you call add_arr(p, q)?

Comment: @Antoine M Ah dang, I'll edit my code. The same thing happens though. Still get the very same error.

Comment: Just checking, but you haven't edited the error in your question. It still shows `----> 1 add_arr(p,q,r)`. You did make sure to reset your environment so you're not running stale bytecode?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Got some immediate and now can't seem to edit it on my phone. But yeah, not stale code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `numpy.ones` to generate a list of ones, and according to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html):

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array, e.g., numpy.int8. Default is numpy.float64.

`np.ones(1000000)` is a list of `numpy.float64` ones. But your `add_arr` spec requires lists of `int64`, hence the `TypeError` blowing up.

A simple fix:

```
p = np.ones(1000000, dtype=np.int64)
q = np.ones(1000000, dtype=np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problems might happen when you call a scipy function such as entr. To correct the system behavior you should specify the data type of your input array to float:

```
from scipy.special import entr
x = np.random.rand(3, 10).astype(float)
print(entr(p))
```